# line art vertex weight transfer is not working properly

Tags: lineart

[image]

Vertex group was set in the face object. The name of the vertex group is lips

[image]

In line art modifier object data property, a vertex group called lips was added.

[image]

After that, in line art modifier, the starting name of the vertex group was put in the filter source.

[image]

Line art has been applied to the entire face.

The problem is that it should only be applied to the lips, but it applies to the entire face.

[image]

Comment: Hey, I saw in a different question that you were having performance problems using the line art modifier.  It can be a beast.  In my workflow I create a separate collection for line art objects, because if I unload the collection, the calculations for the line art objects no longer happen, and I can get work done.

Comment: I see. I'll make a collection and take care of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertex Weight Transfer doesn't do any filtering on it's own -- you have to add additional modifiers on the stack to use the weights that it transfers from the mesh into the line art object to do what you want.

In your case you can add an opacity modifier, and then set it up so that it sets the opacity to zero for line art strokes generated by vertices not in the lips group.

Here's what that set-up looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much :)